# How can i get the membership list of each community in python igraph after running spinglass community detection Algorithm

Tags: python, igraph

I was able to run the spinglass community detection algorithm on my dataset which i was able to the get the memberships. However i want to get the members within each community.I have 11 communities and i want to find the members in community 1 and 2. This is what i have done so far

C=spinglass.membership
the result of C is this [10, 11, 9, 6, 2, 9, 9, 10, 7, 2, 5, 7, 10, 11, 4, 1, 10, 1, 10, 2, 5, 9, 1, 7, 10, 1, 9, 7, 4, 3, 6, 11, 10, 9, 9, 5, 0, 7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 0, 11, 2, 7, 9, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 10, 7, 4, 2, 10, 9, 0, 11, 1, 6, 11, 5, 7, 1, 6, 2, 2, 5, 2, 9, 2, 6, 3, 10, 6, 9, 1, 2, 10, 10, 3, 1, 0, 4, 4, 5, 7, 0, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 7, 9, 5, 6, 6, 5, 3, 7, 4, 6, 11, 2, 10, 1, 5, 3, 3, 9, 2, 3, 10, 9, 0, 9, 1, 10, 0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 2, 7, 5, 11, 11, 7, 9, 3, 10, 6, 0, 7, 3, 5, 7, 5, 5, 5, 10, 0, 6, 0, 1, 4, 6, 11, 11, 7, 1, 9, 11, 11, 3, 3, 5, 11, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 11, 1, 7, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 0, 1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 9, 3, 4, 10, 3, 3, 11, 6, 11, 4, 6, 11, 7, 0, 11, 10, 1, 5, 5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 2, 3, 9, 1, 0, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 11, 5, 11, 2, 0, 0, 4, 2, 3, 9, 11, 2, 9, 1, 7, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 4, 3, 0, 6, 9, 6, 4, 0, 7, 6, 5, 3, 9, 9, 3, 3, 4, 2, 9, 9, 10, 5, 5, 4, 4, 10, 1, 6, 6, 4, 6, 9, 1, 1, 1, 7, 4, 11, 1, 9, 3, 10, 0, 4, 9, 9, 5, 10, 6, 11, 4, 3, 11, 11, 11, 6, 10, 5, 2, 1, 11, 11, 1, 10, 0, 10, 11, 4, 6, 0, 7, 0, 1, 2, 9, 2, 11, 3, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 11, 11, 6, 2, 5, 4, 7, 4, 10, 6, 11, 3, 6, 2, 11, 1, 2, 5, 7, 7, 0, 4, 9, 3, 1, 10, 5, 10, 4, 2, 1, 11, 1, 11, 7, 2, 2, 5, 11, 11, 3, 10, 6, 9, 9, 2, 3, 5, 0, 9, 2, 9, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 10, 2, 7, 5, 5, 1, 0, 3, 4, 7, 1, 5, 1, 1, 10, 4, 7, 5, 10, 9, 9, 2, 0, 6, 7, 7, 7, 1, 11, 9, 1, 9, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 10, 1, 7, 0, 3, 2, 3, 10, 2, 4, 5, 0, 10, 1, 0, 10, 10, 0, 11, 2, 5, 5, 5, 10, 2, 1, 4, 0, 3, 0, 9, 3, 5, 8, 11, 5, 1, 5, 2, 9, 10, 3, 1, 0, 11, 4, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6, 4, 11, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 7, 0, 1, 4, 4, 2, 7, 10, 5, 2, 0, 4]

How can i find the members in each community
Example. Lets say i have 4 communities, how can i find the members in only Community 1.
I am a begginer in python so i really need help with this

Answer (score 0):

Following along the [online docs](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-module.html), we can see that the [Spinglass community algorithm](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_spinglass) should return a [`VertexClustering`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.clustering.VertexClustering-class.html) object.
This itself has functions `.subgraph(idx)`, and `.subgraphs()`, respectively, which should return the corresponding subgraph for a single cluster (`.subgraph(idx)`), or all of them (`.subgraphs()`).